# is is possible to infer the parent span?

Tags: opentracing

Is there a way to infer a relation between spans without passing the parent span ID to the child service based on other information about the transaction?

We are looking at using opentracing to capture timing information for an end-to-end command/response flow to embedded devices.  As I understand it, in order to combine multiple spans into a coherent trace of the whole operation, a span needs to know its parent so it can report that it has a "child of" or "follows from" relationship with that span.  For most of our system, that is not a problem, but our system has one service that sends commands to the device over SMS and another service that receives the replies via UDP.  We do not have space in our SMS budget to send the context out to the device, although we do have a unique identifier for the device and an incrementing sequence number for the command.

One way I thought of tackling this problem is to have the sending service write its span ID to a database and have the receiver look up the span ID in the database when it gets a reply.  This just seems like a very heavyweight solution to the problem, so I thought I would ask if this scenario is something that anyone has run across before.

Answer (score 1):

I think to truly answer this we'd need to know more about the implementation you're using (Zipkin, Jaegar, Instana?) but I'll try to answer this in a generic way that at least discusses a possible solution.

The OpenTracing standard makes it pretty clear that they do not infer this kind of relations on purpose: https://opentracing.io/docs/overview/inject-extract/

> ...there is a tradeoff between the apparent convenience of these black-box inference-based approaches and the freshness and quality of the assembled traces. Per the concern about quality, OpenTracing is an explicit distributed tracing instrumentation standard...

It may still incur additional cost for SMS but if you were being strict about the inject/extract model you could potentially do a custom carrier: https://opentracing.io/docs/overview/inject-extract/#custom-carriers

That implementation is going to be specific based on your tracing solution as OpenTracing really just calls to the SDK provided by your tracer.

**Assuming you can actually guarantee some level of uniquity in the DB records so you aren't mixing up traces**, you could store a common carrier format (text map or dict indicating HTTP headers) in the DB then look up and inject. I would still try to send some kind of UUID over the wire via SMS because both sides guessing at the unique ID for that trace can be problematic.

Depending on the volume of your requests, you may want to use a key-value store such as redis. This may be more performant + you don't need most of the functionality that an RDBMS is going to provide you.

As for UDP return, you should stick with a common carrier format, there are already some that are appropriate for this kind of call over the wire.